# Implementing color change for selection changed in ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, windows-store-apps, listboxitem

I'm working on Telephone App, which have a situation like when a missed call or unanswered call was recorded that phone number should appear red in listbox and when that number is selection changed it should come back to normal item's foreground color.

Xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="370" ItemsSource="{Binding AllMissedCalls}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

I can implement it with VisualStates or I need to code?

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 0):

At first I tried to use the **VisualStateManger**, but later I decided to make differently. I have created a dependency property where it was stored would highlight color and it could be used like this:

```
<ListBoxItem Name="Missed" local:DependencyPhoneClass.ColorOfState="{StaticResource MissedForegroundColor}">
```

Code of dependency property class:

```
public class DependencyPhoneClass : DependencyObject
{
    public static DependencyProperty ColorOfStateProperty;

    public static void SetColorOfState(DependencyObject DepObject, Brush value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(ColorOfStateProperty, value);
    }

    public static Brush GetColorOfState(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (Brush)DepObject.GetValue(ColorOfStateProperty);
    }

    static DependencyPhoneClass()
    {
        ColorOfStateProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CollorOfState",
                                                            typeof(Brush),
                                                            typeof(DependencyPhoneClass),
                                                            new PropertyMetadata(OnColorStateNameChanged));
    }

    private static void OnColorStateNameChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var MyListBoxItem = sender as ListBoxItem;

        if (MyListBoxItem == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This attached property only supports types derived from Control");
        }

        Brush ColorOfState = GetColorOfState(MyListBoxItem);

        if (ColorOfState != null)
        {
            MyListBoxItem.Foreground = ColorOfState;
        }
    }
}
```

I created colors in resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DefaultForegroundColor" Color="Black" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MissedForegroundColor" Color="Red" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="UnansweredForegroundColor" Color="OrangeRed" />
</Window.Resources>
```

ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="PhoneListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="370" Height="100">
    <ListBoxItem Name="Missed" local:DependencyPhoneClass.ColorOfState="{StaticResource MissedForegroundColor}" Content="Daddy: 1" />
    <ListBoxItem Name="Unanswered" local:DependencyPhoneClass.ColorOfState="{StaticResource UnansweredForegroundColor}" Content="Mom: 15" />
    <ListBoxItem Name="Normal" local:DependencyPhoneClass.ColorOfState="{StaticResource DefaultForegroundColor}" Content="Kim: 0" />
</ListBox>
```

Now, the color is set, it must be reset to default value when it is selected. This may be done in several ways:

1. Use the code:

   ```
   private void ListBoxItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       ListBoxItem MyListBoxItem = sender as ListBoxItem;
       Brush DefaultColor = this.Resources["DefaultForegroundColor"] as Brush;

       DependencyPhoneClass.SetColorOfState(MyListBoxItem, DefaultColor);
   }
   ```
2. Or use EventTrigger in XAML:

   ```
   <ListBoxItem.Triggers>
       <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ListBoxItem.Selected">
           <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard>
                   <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Missed" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DefaultForegroundColor}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
               </Storyboard>
           </BeginStoryboard>
       </EventTrigger>
   </ListBoxItem.Triggers>
   ```

Comment: I'm working in Windows Store Apps in which PropertyMetadata lies in Windows.UI.Xaml which throws the following error for ur code, "Erro1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'object' Error2: The best overloaded method match for 'Windows.UI.Xaml.PropertyMetadata.PropertyMetadata(object)' has some invalid arguments" and local:DependencyPhoneClass.ColorOfState="{StaticResource MissedForegroundColor}" shows error "The name "DependencyPhoneClass" does not exist in the namespace "using:ListBoxTest" even though I add this "xmlns:local="using:ListBoxTest""

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not make this sample under **Windows Store Apps**, so I can not say exactly. Most probably, you have to dig into the side of a **dependency property**. I tried to use the **VisualStateManager** in this case, but later refused, because in the case of properties easier.